# How to splitAt a scala list using shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm trying to split a list of size S at N, where it is known that N, M sum up to S. This does not compile:

```
def splitIt[N <: Nat,
            M <: Nat,
            S <: Nat](u: Sized[List[Int], N] {type A = N},
                      v: Sized[List[Int], M] {type A = M},
                      t: Sized[List[Int], S] {type A = S})(implicit sum: SumAux[N, M, S]): Unit = {
  val z = t.splitAt[N]
}
```

**Errors**

```
No implicit view available from List[Int] => scala.collection.GenTraversableLike[S,List[Int]].

not enough arguments for method sizedOps: (implicit evidence$2: List[Int] => scala.collection.GenTraversableLike[S,List[Int]])shapeless.SizedOps[S,List[Int],S]. Unspecified value parameter evidence$2.
```

**Final correct version**

```
def splitIt[N <: Nat,
            M <: Nat, S <: Nat](u: Sized[List[Int], N] {type A = Int},
                                v: Sized[List[Int], M] {type A = Int},
                                t: Sized[List[Int], S] {type A = Int})(implicit sum: DiffAux[S, N, M], toInt: ToInt[N]): Unit = {
  val z = t.splitAt[N]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `type` `A` needs to be *the type of the elements of the list*, not the size argument again.  That's why it's trying to convert to a `GenTraversableLike[A, List[Int]]`.  You need to set `A` to `Int` in each case.

Comment: +1, but this is only the first step—knowing `SumAux[N, M, S]` doesn't get you the `Diff[S, N]` you need to split the list (unfortunately), and you'll also have to add a `ToInt` for `N`.

Comment: Changed the `A`s and added a `toInt` implicit. How to add the `Diff`?

Comment: @Peteris: You can remove the `SumAux` (unless you need it for some other reason in your real code) and add either `Diff[S, N]` or `DiffAux[S, N, M]`.